# How to serve php files from a folder outside of web root folder in nginx

Tags: nginx, php

When i go to url `www.example.gr` i want to load a form where i will be able to submit it to `www.example.gr/php/mail.php`.

My files and folders structure is like this

```
root folder ( /var/www/html/app/ ) with these files:

index.php
test.php
```

```
and a second folder (/var/www/html/assets/ ) with these files:

php/phpmailer/...
php/mail.php
vendor/...
js/...
images/...
css/...
```

my nginx conf is

```
    server {
      server_name example.gr www.example.gr;

      root /var/www/html/app/;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;

      location ^~ /php {
        root /var/www/html/assets/php;
        index mail.php mail.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /php/mail.php?q=$uri&$args;

          
        location ~* \.php(/|$) {
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
          fastcgi_index mail.php;
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/assets/php$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }
      }

      # location /php/ {
      #   alias /var/www/html/assets/php/;
      # }
      location /js/ {
        alias /var/www/html/assets/js/;
      }
      location /vendor/ {
        alias /var/www/html/assets/vendor/;
      }
      location /images/ {
        alias /var/www/html/assets/images/;
      }

      location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }
   }
```

The page `www.example.gr` loads successfully with all images, js, css files but the submition doesn't work, when i go to `www.example.gr/php/mail.php` i get 404 error.

How can i make it work?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you hide the log output? please give you some. minutes to read carefully step by step [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values for `root` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` under the `location ^~ /php` block are incorrect.

The URI currently being processed includes the prefix `/php/` and is combined with the `root` value to form the pathname (as explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root)). So you should not include `php` in the `root` value, otherwise your pathname will contain `.../php/php/...` which will not work.

Try:

```
location ^~ /php {
    root /var/www/html/assets;
    ...
    location ~* \.php(/|$) {
        ...
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

The value of `$document_root` is the same as the value of the `root` statement that is currently in scope.